# CakePHP : site not opening on webserver MIGRATION issue works fine on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Ok so this is whats happening . I am learning cake PHP and recenntly developed a blog using it .
The Blog post and comments are working just fine on the local server .
But when i migrated it to my web server(bluehost). the site doesnt open.
it Says that it could not find index.ctp in the views folder . 
I got around the problem and found out that my folder names in /Views/ 
are in smalls e.g. /Views/posts and not /Views/Posts . The site works prefectly on the local server (the folder names still being /Views/posts). But it doesnt open on the Bluehost server. does it have something with mod_rewrite . PLz help me . Early answer would be appreciated .
Tomorrow is my external Viva and my site doesnt open properly !!!! HELP!

Comment: Please somebody help me ! i have a viva tomorrow ! please help me out friends !

Comment: Now even if i change the folder names . the sote works BUT ! It cannot find the has many association . The comments cannot find the related posts . i.e. $comment['Post']['title']. is Undefined index: Post . And i cannot seem to resolve that. the $comments array dosent seem to carry the post data when i used print_r($comments)

Comment: If your server issue seems to be resolved, I would close this question and open another with more details about your associated records problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try bypassing the url rewriting and hitting the front controller directly (e.g. http://www.example.com/index.php?url=/views/posts)

If that resolves correctly, then you've definitely got an issue with your url rewrite setup.

Comment: Error: Index.phpController could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Did you develop your site on a Windows PC? Windows does not care if the foldernames are upper or lowercase.

Comment: Now even if i change the folder names . the sote works BUT ! 
It cannot find the has many association . The comments cannot find the related posts . i.e. $comment['Post']['title']. is  Undefined index: Post . And i cannot seem to resolve that. the $comments array dosent seem to carry the post data when i used print_r($comments).